# How to use a std::remove'd string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Lets assume the following:

```
string s("!Hello!'");
```

My aim is to obtain in the s variable, only the "Hello" string, IOW I want to remove the exclamation marks.

I tried the following:

```
std::remove ( s.begin(), s.end(), '!' );
```

When I cout the resulting s string I get:

```
Helloo!
```

The "!" chars have been removed, but the end of the string was not moved.

I've read that I need to get back an iterator from the return value of std::remove, but I'm new in C++ and don't succeed in it.

I expect something like char::iterator to be valid, but seems not to be... so

```
char::iterator new_end;
new_end = std::remove ( s.begin(), s.end(), '!' );
cout << new_end ;
```

doesn't make it.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::remove` operates on *iterators*, not containers. Consequently, it cannot resize a container.

You should use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

```
s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '!'), s.end());
```

Here, `remove` implements the removal logic and returns an iterator to the new last element in the sequence – in other words, it reorders the elements but doesn’t touch the container. `erase`, finally, resizes the container by setting its end to what `remove` returned.

Comment: I think you mean `std::remove(s.begin(),..)` instead of `std::string(s.begin(),...)`

Comment: still missing a bit at the end, the second iterator argument to string::erase

Comment: @KerrekSB: Heh, yes, we are all better off if everybody just keeps complaining ;) I suppose you have edit privilege as well?

Comment: It works properly, thank you ! Accepted for simplicity, introducing "erase-remove idiom" and for being a one-liner solution ;)

Comment: Another alternative is `s.resize(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '!')-s.begin())`. Works because string iterators are random access so you have `operator -`, efficient because `resize` never moves elements.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators represent positions in a container. They are designed have similar semantics to pointers to array elements in C. The "end" iterator typically represents the position just after the last element in a container, it is a valid iterator but it can't be dereferenced (you can't use the '*' operator)

In order to remove elements from a container you have to use remove followed by erase. Here is a convenient utility function that you could use that will remove values from a collection.

```
template<typename Collection, typename Element>
void remove_elements(Collection& c, const Element& e) {
    c.erase(std::remove(c.begin(), c.end(), e), c.end());
};
```

Now you can just write:

```
remove_elements(s, '!');
```

Comment: It looks like you made the same mistakes as KonradRudolph's first edit. You need to pass the collection's end iterator to erase too.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, you were correct. Fixed. This really emphasizes how awesome using small functions are. Only one place to fix it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

While others have shown you a solution, suggest you check out Scott Meyer's "[Understanding why remove doesn’t really remove anything](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_aha_moments.html)" (somewhere in the middle of the page -- the whole page makes for interesting reading, BTW).